# How to write associate same table at the same time with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have following 2 tables. One is MEMBER table. The other is ORDER table.
ORDER table has 4 reference include updated_by to MEMBER.id. All ids associate with Member.id.

```
------
MEMBER
------
 id
 name

------
ORDER
------
 id
 order_member_id
 delivery_member_id
 signed_member_id
 update_by
```

I wrote order.ex like following. However it does not work.

```
defmodule Sample.Store.Order do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "orders" do
    field :name :string

    belongs_to :order_member, Sample.Store.Member
    belongs_to :delivery_member, Sample.Store.Member
    belongs_to :signed_member, Sample.Store.Member
    belongs_to :update_by, Sample.Store.Member
  end
```

With ecto, is it impossible to associate with referenced table?
In case of Member, it should be `belongs_to :member, Sample.Store.Member`?

Or is it simpler to write SQL directory?

I would like to know if it possible or not.

Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I'm guessing you need to do `belongs_to :update_by, Sample.Store.Member, foreign_key: :update_by` because by default Ecto appends `_id` which is not present in this field.

Comment: Yes your point is on error. Are there any way to write?

Comment: Are there any solutions to manage it? `because by default Ecto appends _id which is not present in this field`

Comment: Did you try the code in my comment? (`belongs_to :update_by, Sample.Store.Member, foreign_key: :update_by`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set `foreign_key` like

```
   belongs_to :order_member, Sample.Store.Member, foreign_key: :order_member_id
   belongs_to :delivery_member, Sample.Store.Member, foreign_key: :delivery_member_id
```